# IIS is hanging when requesting a folder with anonymous authentication

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, windows-authentication

I recently changed the frontend of a project, to use windows authentication.
But i still want the backend to use forms authentication, I think i read somewhere that it was not possible to use both authentication methods at the same time. But I seem to have it working, sort of.

I'm using umbraco v4.7.2 - To those that doesn't know this CMS, it's basicly just like any other CMS, the backend of the application is the umbraco "backoffice", basicly just an application hidden away in a folder called "~/umbraco/"
This folder has a custom membership provider configured in the web.config.

The frontend site authenticates users automaticly using windows authentication with a role/group restriction. And this is pretty fast, no problems there.
But when i try to access the umbraco folder, which is configured to enable anonymous access, IIS just hangs for at least a minute, before sending me to the login page.

And after the initial hang, i am able to browse the backend fine, but if i leave the backend, and go to the frontend of the application, and then back to the backend, i get the same hanging again. etc.

I tried debugging the code from visual studio, but all i get is some obscure disassembly, which i am unable to make any sense of.

EDIT: This is very odd, as requesting the folder "umbraco" is very slow, but after waiting and being redirected to "umbraco/login.aspx", refreshing this page, or any other page in umbraco  is not slow at all. But requesting the folder "umbraco/" is still very slow.

Fiddler

```
  ServerGotRequest:    10:09:21.352
  ServerBeginResponse: 10:11:11.961
  GotResponseHeaders:  10:11:11.961
  ServerDoneResponse:  10:11:11.961
```

After the ServerGotRequest, something is making IIS hang.
I will try and create another folder with the same configuration, and see if this also happens then.

Has anyone got any clues to what might cause this?

Thanks :)

Comment: "like any other cms", the same way a ferrari is an 18 wheeler because they both drive on roads?

Comment: The same way a ferrari is a car because it has 4 wheels, a steering wheel and an engine...